# how do I use egrep for searching string

Tags: text-processing, grep

I want to search for string that have 
[RT]"anything"D 
which mean first character can either be R or T 
and the next can be anything until D is appear
what should I use
is it "egrep"?

Comment: can you give me an example? I don't know what i should write.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: please check an edited.

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

If you have GNU grep with it's Perl-compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) support (enabled with `-P`) then you can do it this way:

```
grep -o -P 'RT.*?D' file
```

We want PCRE because it has the [lazy quantifier](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution) (`?`) which we can use with `.*` instead of `.*` alone. The latter is greedy and will slurp up everything until the *last* `D`...

```
$ grep -o 'RT.*D' <<< "JKIRTTHIUCDELKJUCDE"
RTTHIUCDELKJUCD
$ grep -o -P 'RT.*?D' <<< "JKIABTHIUCDELKJUCDE"
RTTHIUCD
```

Oh, and the `-o` flag tells `grep` to print only the matching part of a line rather than the default behavior of printing the entire line.

*Note: this was merged from a similar, now closed-as-duplicate question that had one important difference: the last part of the pattern was multi-character as opposed to the single `D` here. The single-character case can be handled without PCRE (see the other answer here) but the multi-character case requires functionality not available with BRE or ERE syntax.*

Comment: @terdon Seems like the merged question this came from had a critical difference that makes my answer sort of overkill for this question and the other answer here not sufficient for the merged question. (See the added note in my answer.) A little confusing, no?

Comment: Well, it's still useful IMO since it shows the point of non-greedy patterns. Maybe it's because I don't find it overkill at all, this is exactly how I'd do it anyway since writing `.*?` is simpler and shorter than `[^D]*`. And since the other was under the process of being closed, I felt it was better to save your answer. Especially if other, similar questions are also closed as dupes.

Comment: Fair enough. I thought perhaps the duplicate was this question but sounds like it was another (I don't see the closed one any more.)

Comment: It's [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/415186), it's shown under the "linked " section at the top right.

Comment: Oh, so this is the dup. I just think they're fundamentally different since one answer here only works for one of them. But, oh well, I'm not gonna lose any sleep over it.

Answer (score 4):

As the comment said. `grep` is enough to do the work. Write your pattern as `[RT].*D`.

To get the first appearance of `D`, use `[RT][^D]*D`.

There was a caret in the pattern which I have added because of the "first character" in the question. Having realized that the phrase may mean something different I have now removed the carets.

Comment: my output for D is the last occurance of D. Can I get first occurance of D after R or T?How?

Comment: Yes, see updated answer.