# grep a sequnce of 'AB<anything>CDE'

Tags: grep, pattern-matching

I want to grep for '`AB...CDE`', where `...` stands for anythings until `CDE` first occurs.

I have tried `grep 'AB*CDE' filename` but this matches til the last occurrence of `CDE`.

How can fix this?

Suppose that my input is:
`JKIABTHIUCDELKJUCDE`

and I want output as:
 `ABTHIUCDE`

which mean from `AB` until `CDE`